# react native Boolean condition for react-native-orientation of react-native-video

Tags: react-native, video

I am seriously new to the React native subject. I am stuck at really simple checking condition of video player orientations.

My steps of code are :

1. The below code is my state which is `boolean`.

```js
state = {
    viewmode: false,
};
```

2.The below line of code are my icons of video player (landscape and portrait).

```js
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.changeViewModes}>
  <MIcon name={!this.state.viewmode ? "fullscreen" : "fullscreen-exit"} size={30} color="#FFF"></MIcon>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Till here everything worked good so far. but When it comes to the requirement, the video player has to rotate to landscape mode and portrait mode.
So I wrote one condition where its not working properly and showing only one mode either portrait or landscape but not rotating

```js
changeViewModes = () => {
  if (!this.state.viewmode == false) {
    //fullscreen
    this.player.presentFullscreenPlayer();
    Orientation.lockToLandscape();
  } else {
    //fullscreen_exit
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();
  }
};
```

4. Video component code

```html
<Video  paused={this.state.paused}
        source={LightVideo}
        style={{ width: "100%", height }}
        resizeMode="contain"
        onLoad={this.handleLoad}
        onProgress={this.handleProgress}
        onEnd={this.handleEnd}
        ref={ref =>

 { this.player = ref;}}
          />
```

Can anyone help me to rotate my video player to landscape mode to portrait mode and vice versa.

Comment: viewmode(true) means not full screen?

Comment: @Lenoarod  The exact problem is that when , When page is loaded, video player will be in portrait mode but when I click the full screen mode it turns to full screen and landscape mode which I want, but now if I click again , then It will still be in landscape mode only. Its not rotating to portrait mode again.

Comment: @Lenoarod please look into the edit. I have pasted the video component code and icon changes

Comment: when fullscreen exit handle by manual, you also have to call `dismissFullscreenPlayer `

Comment: @Lenoarod its not working

Comment: did you use my code update `viewmode` state?

Comment: oh, Sorry I understand your logic wrong. your state ViewModel is reverse to control screen

Comment: the rest of problem may be caused by the component width and height you set

Comment: @Lenoarod i did

Answer (score 0):

I assets the `viewmodel` true means fullscreen. and you click your Mico to change the fullscreen.

```
// this is your video component
Video source={{uri: "background"}}   
       ref={(ref) => {
         this.player = ref
       } />
```

```
state = {
viewmode: false, // true means full screen
};

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = {this.changeViewModes}>
              <MIcon name = {!this.state.viewmode ? "fullscreen" : "fullscreen-exit"} size = {30} color="#FFF"></MIcon>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

changeViewModes = () => {

if(!this.state.viewmode)
{ 
  //fullscreen
  this.player.presentFullscreenPlayer();
  Orientation.lockToLandscape();

} else {

  //fullscreen_exit
  this.player.dismissFullscreenPlayer()  // you don not call this method
  Orientation.lockToPortrait(); 

}
// you also have to update the state
this.setState({
   viewModel:!viewModel

})

}
```

Comment: even its true or false my code is not working . The exact problem is that when , When page is loaded video player will be in portrait mode but when I click the full screen mode it turns to full screen and landscape mode which I want, but now if I click again , then It will still be in landscape mode only. Its not rotating to portrait mode again.

Comment: firstly, your code does not change the state, so the icon does not change with status.  and please gives your video component code.